# Bypass Windows Server login screen

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, login

I am accessing Windows Server using RDP from Windows XP SP3. The issue is i am getting the Windows Server Screen asking me to enter the password again after injecting the username and password in RDP. Is there a way i bypass the Windows Server login screen so that i do not want to enter the credential again. On windows 7 it works fine but not in XP.

Comment: What version of Windows Server is this about?

Comment: Are you referring to having a saved RDP file from MSTSC that contains the username and password saved within?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can save the user and password in your RDP-profile the same way as unter windows 7. There are two things that can prevent you to do this:

- The version of your RDP client software under Windows XP. Check that you have Version 6 or higher.
- If the XP PC is member of a domain, there is a domain policy to prevent you saving login credentials. Ask your domain administrator if this policy is set and whether he can make an exception for you.